# SQL Server JOIN/APPLY Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, cross-apply, outer-apply

What join should I use to get my desired output base on dummy table below

**DETAIL TABLE**

```
x------------------------------x
| empID | empName | date       |
x------------------------------x
| 1     | emp1    | 10/01/2016 |
| 1     | emp1    | 10/03/2016 |
| 1     | emp1    | 10/04/2016 |
| 1     | emp1    | 10/05/2016 |
| 1     | emp1    | 10/06/2016 |
x------------------------------x
```

**LIST DATES FROM 10/01/2016 to 10/15/2016 OF TABLE**

```
x------------x
| date       |
x------------x
| 10/01/2016 |
| 10/02/2016 |
| .......... |
| .......... |
| 10/15/2016 |
x------------x
```

**Desired output for my query**

```
x------------------------------x
| empID | empName | date       |
x------------------------------x
| 1     | emp1    | 10/01/2016 |
| null  | null    | 10/02/2016 |
| 1     | emp1    | 10/03/2016 |
| 1     | emp1    | 10/04/2016 |
| 1     | emp1    | 10/05/2016 |
| 1     | emp1    | 10/06/2016 |
| null  | null    | 10/07/2016 |
| null  | null    | 10/08/2016 |
| null  | null    | 10/09/2016 |
| null  | null    | 10/10/2016 |
| null  | null    | 10/11/2016 |
| null  | null    | 10/12/2016 |
| null  | null    | 10/13/2016 |
| null  | null    | 10/14/2016 |
| null  | null    | 10/15/2016 |
x------------------------------x
```

Comment: Why `empID` for non matching records ?

Comment: I forgot to change the desired output empID, empName should be null if no date is matching on the list of date range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is `OUTER JOIN` it can be either `LEFT` or `RIGHT` depending on where you are using the `detail` table.

```
SELECT D.empid, 
       D.empname, 
       LD.[date] 
FROM   detail D 
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN list_dates LD 
                     ON D.[date] = LD.[date]
```

Also you can use `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT D.empid, 
       D.empname, 
       LD.[date] 
FROM   list_dates LD 
       OUTER apply (SELECT * 
                    FROM   detail D 
                    WHERE  D.[date] = LD.[date]) D
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need an `outer join`:

```
select e.empid, e.empname, d.date
from dates d 
   left join detail e on d.date = e.date
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)